# Confusing configuration in HttpClient v5 ConnectionBackoffStrategy or HttpRequestRetryStrategy

Tags: http, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpclient-5.x

I need some mechanism to sleep then retry if I get `429` response.

I suppose implementing the `HttpRequestRetryStrategy` more suitable. But I'm confused when I saw `ConnectionBackoffStrategy` interface.

Which one should I use? And why?

I have a concern about connections. If the http client instance is slept for example **30-60 min**, what happened with my connections in `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`? Are they still alive?
Or they are evicted?